# Are FK in the DB needed if they're simulated at an ORM level with SqlAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

So I recently inherited a few apps that use SqlAlchemy backed by a common MySQL DB. I'm pretty green to python, and have no experience with SqlAlchemy.

1 system has FKs defined for the tables that are only used within that app. However, none of the other tables have any constraints defined. All of the relationships of other tables are defined at the application level within the ORM. Being green to SqlAlchemy, I'm now wondering if this was just sloppy code evolution, or if there could be a logical explanation for this inconsistency.

What are the Pros/Cons are relying solely on the ORM for relationships vs keeping constraints in sync between persistence and application levels?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

DB FKs offer two significant benefits:

1. it will create an index which will optimize the join performance
2. it will ensure at the DB level that your application cannot stick an invalid key which does not have a peer, which strengthen its consistency

Unless you need the flexibility in the DB to have invalid keys, I'd highly recommend FK constraints on all relationships you plan to join on.